# Will change of constructor's prototype influence the instantiated object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

If I have a function (constructor) with a defined prototype, let's say:

```
function Student(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Student.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
}
```

And I instantiate and object using that function (from what I know it should set newly created object's property `_prototype` to the above prototype object in the moment of creation and set `constructor` property to `Student` function).

```
const s1 = new Student('John');
s1.sayHello();
```

I am sure calling `sayHello()` would work, however, what if I change the `Student`'s prototype like this?

```
Student.prototype.sayGoodbye = function() {
  console.log(`Goodbye, my name is ${this.name}`);
}
```

Should `s1` be able to call `sayGoodbye`?

I've read that the `_prototype` should't change, so in that logic it should throw an error, however, trying it in Chrome's console panel and node.js project it worked and s1 could invoke `sayGoodbye`. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: The prototype isn't being *copied* when you instantiate the object. It literally points to that one prototype object. Whatever you add to that object is visible on anything that points to it.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your input :). That makes much more sense. The reference to prototype will last during all the object's lifetime and be shared between all the objects constructed from the same function.

Only when we will have already a few objects with the same prototype and the prototype will be changed to a new object, the next objects will have a new reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `_prototype` means. Do you mean `.__proto__`? Or `.prototype`? Those two are different things (and `.__proto__` is deprecated, in favour of `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`, and similar `Reflect` methods).

There are a couple of different meanings of "change the prototype".

1. Replace the `[[Prototype]]`, like with `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Besides the possible implications on the readability, there is also the performance factor, summarised in this warning from the MDN:

   > **Warning**: Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to the time spent in the `Object.setPrototypeOf(...)` statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose `[[Prototype]]` has been altered. You can read more in JavaScript engine fundamentals: optimizing prototypes.

   > Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the burden on engine developers to implement that feature performantly (ideally). Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about performance, you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using `Object.create()`.

2. Modify the `[[Prototype]]` of built-in or library objects, by replacing or adding properties. This is discouraged mainly because it is not future-proof. For example, `Array.prototype.find` is a pretty useful function, which did not exist in, say, 2012. If someone added it to the array prototype, it would have been useful then, but when it got implemented a few years later, anyone who defined `Array.prototype.find` on their own would have been replacing a more efficient code with the less efficient one.

   You could guard against it and only replace the function if it wasn't already defined, but then incompatibilities could arise. The now-standard `.find` will return `undefined` when it can't find a matching element. If your polyfill is returning `null`, but you leave alone the built-in `.find` in case it exists, and your code behaves differently on `null` and `undefined`, you have a problem.
3. Modify the `[[Prototype]]` of your own objects, by defining or replacing properties on the prototype. It seems this is the meaning you are using in your question. *Shrug.* It's your code.

   Yes, any changes to the prototype properties will be reflected in the prototyped objects, unless they are overshadowed by the properties on the prototyped objects. As deceze explains in their comment, the prototype properties are not copied onto the prototyped object at creation time. Instead, at lookup time, the property is checked on the prototyped object, then on the prototype, then on the prototype's prototype, going up the prototype chain until it is found (or, if no such property is found until the end of the chain is reached at the root object, returning `undefined`). Thus, if you add a property to a prototype, it makes no difference when the property is added, whether before or after the creation of a prototyped object, as long as it is before the property is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question "Should s1 be able to call sayGoodbye?"
Yes, it should.
To be clear why. You have to understand the [[prototype]] chain. Any constructor function like your function:

```
function Student(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

is an object which has a .prototype property. Any instance of that constructor function `var student = new Student("name");` will have a property `__proto__` which will point to `Student.prototype` which in turn has a `__proto__` property which point to Object.prototype (the end of the [[prototype]] chain).
now, when you add a property to any prototype node in that chain -let's say `sayGoodbye`- it will be seen by the instance `student`, because when you call it like this: `student.sayGoodbye()`, JS engine will look for it in student object if it did not find it, then the engine will look for it in what ever `student.__proto__` refer to, which in our case `Student.prototype` if it also did not find it there it will continue lokking in the [[prototype]] chain until it find it or reach the end of the chain which is `Object.prototype`.